# Where is rbenv gem's rdoc?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rdoc, rbenv

I'm using `rbenv` and I'm trying to figure out where the rdoc of my local gems are located.

When I install a gem, it says the rdoc are properly generated, i.e.:

```
% gem install rails -v "2.3.2"
Successfully installed rails-2.3.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-2.3.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-2.3.2...
```

But I cannot figure out where the rdoc files are, in my `~/.rbenv` directory I found a `doc` folder: `.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/doc` with folders for local gems in it, each of them contain `rdoc` and `ri` folders but they are empty.

Answer (score 4):

Run `gem env gemdir` to see where you're installing gems.  The docs should be under `$(gem env gemdir)/doc`.

You also might want to make sure you are installing gems with the version of gem you think you are.  `which gem` should point to `~/.rbenv/shims/gem` (if it doesn't try `hash -r` to clear the shell's cache of executable locations).  Also, `rbenv which gem` should point to the gem executable for your current ruby version (which you can find out using `rbenv version`). If it doesn't, make sure you `rbenv rehash`, which you must do every time you install a new gem with executables.